# Jquery Tablesorter 2.0 issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I've got a question about jQuery plugin tablesorter 2.0.

I'm using it to display all users from my database.

**Columns:**

```
Name, Firstname, Initial, Department
```

Each initial should be clickable.

For testing, I added following code:

```
$("#initial a").click(function() {
    var userInitial = $(this).text();
    $("#addedUser").append(userInitial);
});
```

The problem is, this only works with the first page (10 users).

So if I go on the second page (or change items/site to 20) the new initials which are shown now aren't clickable. You can still just click the first 10 initials. Why?

I'd be very happy if someone helps me solve this problem.

Comment: could you post the part where you attach the plugin's functionality to the table?

Comment: Plugin attachment:
http://nopaste.info/4cbefd71e1.html

The db output:
<td width="100" id="initial"><a id="<?php echo $id; ?>" href="#plan"><?php echo $initial; ?></a></td>

Comment: I figured out that something goes wrong with my code, when the pager plugin is added. After removing, the whole thing  is working (but doesn't look very nice with over 300 entries/site). 
I don't know why this doesn't work with the pager plugin. Is there a bug which I don't know? Because I'm using the same pager.js file in a other table and there it's working perfect...

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.
The function .live() was the solution.

```
  $(".add").live("click", function() {
      var user = $(this).text();
      $("#addedUser").append(user+" ");
  });
```